# Check version of a *.aar file module from a FlatDir

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

My Android App is using a *.aar Library Module. In the gradle file of my App i have :

```
compile 'com.bar.core:fbi-framework:1.0.0@aar'
```

In my Library Module gradle file i have :

```
defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        version "1.0.0"        }
```

But when i change the dependency version in my app gradle File like this:

```
compile 'com.bar.core:fbi-framework:1.0.1@aar'
```

"1.0.1" instead of "1.0.0" No error is raised when synchronizing or when building. So i don't understand how module version is checked from a module dependency.

To complete by an other example. When i change

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
```

by

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:19.4.0'
```

Gradle sends

> Failed to resolve and sync project

because the library doesn't exist. So is there a difference between library from maven central or jcenter and a *.aar file from a flatDir ? How in the first case the version is checked ?

Thanks for your help

regards